# how to handle query with large result? (for search bar)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm adding a search bar for people to search for other people on my database, but I'm worry that the search will return to much rows. I just want to stop the query, and return none if its to large.

how do I stop the query from continuing if the result is to big(ex.100s of rows)?

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php

Comment: won't "limit" still complete the query? I just need a way to stop the query before it gather 100s and 100s of result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can "stop" the query. But if you really want to count the number of rows first you can do it as following:

Let's say your search query looks like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE name = 'some name';
```

You can first count the results

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
FROM table_name
WHERE name = 'some name';
```

And then only select the rows (first query) if *num <= 100*

To combine both queries into one you can use a `CROSS JOIN`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
    FROM table_name
    WHERE name = 'some name'
) num
CROSS JOIN table_name
WHERE num.num <= 100
AND name = 'some name'
```

If *num* is *> 100* MySQL will stop, because there is nothing to join.

But:

- Its not user friendly - you better use `LIMIT` and use (or implement) a paging system.
- No guaranty that it would be faster than using `LIMIT`
- It will be slower in all cases where *num <= 100*

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 30";
```